# How to add module mappings in powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

Pretty new to PowerShell and so far what I have is this and not working. Any ideas?

```
Add-WebConfiguration system.webServer/handlers -Location $mySite -Name "html" -Modules "someModule" -Path ".html" -Type "System.Web.Handlers" -Verb "GET,HEAD"
```

Comment: Please post what you mean by "not working"

Comment: Thank you for helping. It gives an error saying "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name". Have no idea how to properly add a module map using powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PowerShell online help is excellent, [Add-WebConfiguration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh867867.aspx).

But, I think you want to use the WebHandler commandlets instead, most likely [New-WebHandler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh867892.aspx)

```
> New-WebHandler -Name "html" -Path "*.html" -Verb 'GET,POST' -Modules IsapiModule `
-PSPath $mySite
```

If that doesn't work for you, you can look at [Set-WebHandler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh867852.aspx)